# Determine limits using $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$

Tags: limits

> Using $\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ , Find $\lim_{x \to \pi/4} = \frac{\sin x - \cos x}{x- \frac{\pi}{4}}$

My work:

$\frac{ \sin x}{x - \frac{\pi}{4}}(\frac{x}{x})  -\frac{ \cos x}{x - \frac{\pi}{4}}$

$\frac{ x}{x - \frac{\pi}{4}} - \frac{ \cos x}{x - \frac{\pi}{4}}$

However, when I substitute $x=\pi/4$, I do not get the required answer of $\sqrt{2}$ because the denominator is still $ x - \frac{\pi}{4} =0$

Comment: You can use that $\sin x - \cos x= \sqrt 2 \sin (x-\pi/4)$ or set $y=x-\pi/4 \to 0$

Comment: @user i dont quite get your hint on how are they equal

Comment: Try expanding $\sqrt{2}\sin\left(x - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$.

Comment: Is Lhopital allowed?

Comment: @hersh nope, Im doing it without that rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute the following

$t = x - \frac{\pi}{4}$

Notice that as $x \to \frac{\pi}{4}$, $t \to 0$

Change the limit to get the following

$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\sin(t + \frac{\pi}{4}) - \cos(t + \frac{\pi}{4})}{t}$

Use addition formulae and get the following

$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\sin t}{t}$

Notice the simplification, which leads us directly to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the trick here is to modify the numerator in order to 'tidy things up':

$$\sqrt2 \left(\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt2} - \frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt2}\right)$$

Now we notice that $\frac{1}{\sqrt2} = \sin(\frac{\pi}{4}) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{4})$ allowing us to factorize the numerator nicely as $\sin(x - \frac{\pi}{4})$, resulting in the full equation:

$$\frac{\sqrt2(\sin(x - \frac{\pi}{4}))}{x - \frac{\pi}{4}}$$

From this, it is clear how we can make use of the $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$.